# IIS Not Serving PHP pages

Tags: php, iis

I have followed these instructions exactly, yet I get a "Page cannot be found" 404 error
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/

My PHP file is

```
 <?php
 phpinfo();
 ?>
```

I am running Windows Server 2003 and installed FastCGI and made sure everything is correct per those instructions. I can also create an HTML page and that serves no problem, so it must be an issue with PHP. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: does a regular CGI configuration work?

Comment: Can you point me to a place to set that?

Comment: have you checked the IIS logs?

Comment: how to set up CGI: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bc0c4729-e892-4871-b8f3-fcbf489f2f09.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I followed the steps here http://www.visualwin.com/PHP/ but it hangs for awhile, I see php.exe in Task Manager. If I kill the processm I get CGI Error on the page.

Comment: Did you see the note: *the EXE name is "php-cgi.exe" instead of "php.exe", so when installing PHP 5, remember to replace "php.exe" in this tutorial with "php-cgi.exe"* ?

Comment: @Janus Troelsen Still get page cannot be found

Comment: have you checked the IIS logs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9479/discussion-between-isaac-levin-and-janus-troelsen)

Comment: i dont see anything pressing in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IIS is serving flat html file from the site you've setup PHP on, it's time to check the php log file. Most likely, there are some errors occuring due to the php configuration (php.ini), and php is not displaying the errors to the screen. This happens to me a lot when I setup a new install of php under IIS.

Look in your php.ini file to find the location of you're log file. If the log file isn't being written to that directory, make sure the directory is writable by PHP. This will be the user the app pool is configured to use (by default it something like network service, iis_usr, or the like). Make sure that user has fill write permissions on the log file directory.

Also double check your windows event log to see if there were any suppressed popup messages that may help identify the problem. This can happen on some of the older versions of windows server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like PHP isn't being invoked for that file name extension.  From there, PHP isn't a registered file type/extension for IIS, so IIS returns a 404 rather than returning the raw file itself.

I would double check to make sure FastCGI is configured correctly.  Try running PHP as regular CGI if possible (as suggested by Janus).