# What are the steps to move a MediaWiki website?

Tags: mysql, iis-7.5, iis-6, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to move MediaWiki websites from Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) to Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5). I installed the same version of MediaWiki to the destination server in order to avoid conflict. I dumped, move and restore the MySQL database; zip, move and restore the MediaWiki files which includes the images, LocalSettings.php files for each MediaWiki website.

I can't browse the websites now, I believe I need to do something else but I am not sure. I am totally new to MediaWiki. Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
$wiki_name          = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1, strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/", 1) - 1);
$wgScriptPath       = "/${wiki_name}";
$wgLogo             = "images_${wiki_name}/${wiki_name}_logo.gif";
$wgUploadPath       = "$wgScriptPath/images_${wiki_name}";      
$wgUploadDirectory  = "$IP/images_${wiki_name}";              
require_once("LocalSettings.${wiki_name}.php");
unset($wiki_name);
```

LocalSettings.php has above section which has a purpose of using multiple mediawiki websites. And each LocalSettings.website.php files have section below:

```
$wgDBtype           = "mysql";
$wgDBserver         = "localhost";
$wgDBname           = "database";
$wgDBuser           = "user";
$wgDBpassword       = "password";
```

in order to identify which database is used by each website.

[image]
This is the picture I got when I browsed the MediaWiki wiki through IIS.

And from server log I got the following:

```
#Date: 2014-10-06 19:42:17
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-10-06 19:42:17 ::1 GET /mediawiki - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 301 0 0 265
2014-10-06 19:42:17 ::1 GET /mediawiki/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 200 0 0 78
```

Comment: Any db specific settings in LocalSettings.php? What do your server logs say?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope I answered the question.

Comment: Does `$wiki_name` contain what you expect it to? Did you try replacing `$wiki_name` with whatever it should be?
And what does the server's error log tell you?

Comment: I made a change you said and edited the question

Comment: Sorry, I meant an error log, that looks like an access log. And again, does `$wiki_name` actually get the right value? (BTW, what is the reason for the unusual construction with `$wiki_name`? Are you having multiple wikis sharing the same LocalSettings.php?)

Comment: I am not sure about the wiki_name get, but I changed it to wikiname = "wikiname". Yes I have one shared localsettings.php which direct to localsettigs.website1.php, localsettings.website2.php etc. What do you mean by the error. I dont get any error when I browse the website through iis. It shows me the picture that i've attached to the question which is directories and files inside mediawiki folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62545/discussion-between-leo-and-user1722022).

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS Not Serving PHP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912580/iis-not-serving-php-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about IIS declaration of virtual directory. And additionally needed to add index.asp and index.php files as default document through IIS.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you use? AdminSettings.php was removed in MW 1.16, so you should consider to upgrading your wiki, this as a side note :)

You said, you have installed a new version of MediaWiki? Are there all files on your server? (Check the list from github e.g. https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/tree/REL1_16).

Best!

Comment: I kept old one just to make sure, it is stable enough.

Comment: Can you check my idea please? What is, if you open the index.php file within the url?

Comment: just solved the problem. IIS virtual directory wasn't declared correctly.